# Is there an alternative to session that I can pull once rather than throughout the whole session? Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to dynamically add pictures based on the url that is visited but when I try to go to another url it won't change it from the main image. I think the issue is that it is using session and is holding the same value over the whole session.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'ThisIsSecret'

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/ninja')
def allninjas():

    session['picture'] = url_for('static', filename='tmnt.png')

    return render_template('ninja.html')

@app.route('/ninja/orange')
def orangeninja():

    session['picture'] = url_for('static', filename='michelangelo.jpg')

    return redirect('/ninja')

@app.route('/ninja/red')
def redninja():

    session['picture'] = url_for('static', filename='raphael.jpg')

    return redirect('/ninja')

@app.route('/ninja/purple')
def purpleninja():

    session['picture'] = url_for('static', filename='donatello.jpg')

    return redirect('/ninja')

@app.route('/ninja/blue')
def blueninja():

    session['picture'] = url_for('static', filename='leonardo.jpg')

    return redirect('/ninja')


app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the url of picture to the template file directly?